# How to create lampstreet particle in Evee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, hair

I want to create a large city a night in Eevee. I tried to add streetlamp as a hair system, but I can't add the emitting lamp with it. Is there a way to link the emitting lamp to my object (a streetlamp) so I can create with an hair system hundreds of streetlamp with their own lights ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Keep in mind that Eevee has a [limitation of 128 lights](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/limitations.html?highlight=128%20lights) in a scene

Answer (score 3):

1. Put the streetlamp model and the light emitter into an own collection, let's say you call it "streetlight".
2. In the Particle Emitter settings under *Render* > *Render As* choose "Collection".
3. For the *Instance Collection* choose the created "streetlight" collection.
4. Check "Whole Collection" underneath. This is usually not desired if you have collections of different trees, stones or whatever because you want them to be picked randomly. But in this case this means each particle is now the streetlamp model with the light at the correct place.